# Creating a UDP server using IO::Socket::INET without specifying a port

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, udp, io-socket

I am trying to create a `UDP` server using `perl` `IO::Socket::INET`.

I am facing difficulty with using the following parameters:

- `LocalHost => "0.0.0.0"`
- `LocalPort => 0`

What I am trying to achieve is to:

- Listen on all NICs, hence the use of `0.0.0.0`
- Have the OS pick a port, hence the use of `0` as the `LocalPort`

Using the parameters above with `TCP`, works just fine. When using those parameters for `UDP`, it doesn't work.

What I found to work with `UDP`, was specifying a `LocalPort` to something fixed and not specifying `LocalHost` at all, however this is not what I need.

The perl code I have is as follows:

```
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(
              LocalHost => "0.0.0.0",
              LocalPort => 0,
              Proto => 'udp') or die "failed $@";
```

What I use to assess if I achieved what I need or not is by checking the output of `lsof -p <pid>`. The following table summarizes what I am seeing in my trials:

| Protocol | LocalHost | LocalPort | `sockport()` output | `lsof -p` output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0 | 0 | 48589 | TCP *:48589 (LISTEN) |
| UDP | 0.0.0.0 | 0 | 0 | protocol: UDP |
| UDP | ***Not specified*** | 50001 | 50001 | UDP *:50001 |
| UDP | output of `hostname()` | 0 | 58066 | UDP hostname:58066 |
| UDP | output of `hostname()` | 50001 | 50001 | UDP hostname:50001 |

The `TCP` trial in the first row's is what I am trying to achieve but for `UDP` and I am unable to.

Comment: What is your rationale to use undefined/random port for UDP server? Are you intending to specify server UDP port for each client on it's start? How a client will know what port on the server it should connect to? Note: network ports 0-1024 require administrative/root privileges to be utilized.

Comment: Why do you not want a port?  Even if you can do that -- what I am not sure about -- How are clients going to know where to write?  (Simply leaving port out runs without errors but I can't see any port on which this server is)

Comment: @PolarBear I call `sockport()` after the socket is created and a job is spawned on another machine with the port as a parameter and it sends stuff back.
This script takes time to run and it should be possible to run it multiple times. Having a fixed port number will make it fail on the second run.

Comment: @zdim Not specifying a port is equivalent to passing 0 as the port number. This means that the OS will pick the port number for you. By calling `$sock->sockport()` after creating the socket will give you the port number that got opened. Also, inspecting the output of lsof -p <pid> of the perl process should give you the port number.